# Chorus of Sia - Big Girls Cry

Tags: meaning, difference, singular-vs-plural

The last two lines from the chorus of Sia's song *Big Girls Cry*:

> Big girls cry when their hearts are breaking
>
> Big girls cry when their heart is breaking

How is the shift from plural to singular justified? What is the difference between the two sentences? What is the artist trying to convey with the shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Big girls cry when their hearts are breaking.
>
> Big girls cry when their heart is breaking.

Both versions sound perfectly fine but carry different understandings, it's much more like a matter of style.

In the first line the author wants to convey the meaning that the plural makes it sound as though the girls are crying with more than one heart whereas in the second line they are being referred to collectively, as though they were all one body sharing a single heart.